# Finding routes path from url string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, routes, request

I want to know what is the route of api request.

Lets say for example `api_v1_user_session`_path is the route for `/api/v1/users/sign_in` url

If a request is coming from `/api/v1/users/sign_in` How can I find out what is the route. In this scenario it should be `api_v1_user_session`_path

I tried below statement but it is giving controller and action but not route.

```
Rails.application.routes.recognize_path('/api/v1/users/sign_in')
=> {:controller=>"api/v1/sessions", :action=>"new"}
```

Is there any method like this

```
Rails.application.routes.get_route('/api/v1/users/sign_in')
=> api_v1_user_session
```

How can I get this route from url or from `request` object.

Comment: You want to get back the method that generates the route?

Comment: I'm not sure what that means, but I'm looking for the route that we get from `rake routes`. I would give input as `url` from `request` object and expect output route.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With more search I was able to figure it myself.

```
class StringToRoute

  attr_reader :request, :url, :verb

  def initialize(request)
    @request = request
    @url = request.original_fullpath
    @verb = request.request_method.downcase
  end

  def routes
    Rails.application.routes.routes.to_a
  end

  def recognize_path
    Rails.application.routes.recognize_path(url, method: get_verb)
  end

  def process
    _recognize_path = recognize_path
     routes.select do |hash|
       if hash.defaults == _recognize_path
         hash
       end
     end
  end

  def get_verb
    verb.to_sym
  end

  def path
    "#{verb}_#{process.name}"
  end
end
```

**Result:**

`StringToRoute.new(request).path`

Comment: Nice solution! (More people should be so willing to roll up their sleeves and dig into the framework when necessary.)

Comment: Should make this into a gem